# .NET MVC accept List<t> as parameter when using JSON and ExtJS 4.1.1

Tags: json, list, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs4

I am trying to make an Ajax request to a .NET MVC Controller.  When I put a break point in the controller code, I notice that the data is null.  I would expect it to have data.

ExtJS code:

```
var paramsList = [];
console.log(paramsList);
for (var i = 0; i < dropData.records.length; i++) {
    if (dropData.records[i].data.Conflicts.indexOf('This Camp' == -1)) {
        //add this cabin to the parameters object
        //idCampEventCabin = 0 tells the server to insert a new CampEventCabin
        paramsList.push({ idCampEventCabin: 0, Abbreviation: dropData.records[i].data.Abbreviation, Accommodations: dropData.records[i].data.Accommodations, Capacity: dropData.records[i].data.Capacity, idCabin: dropData.records[i].data.idCabin, Level: dropData.records[i].data.Level, Name: dropData.records[i].data.Name, Number: dropData.records[i].data.Number, Type: dropData.records[i].data.Type, idCampEvent: form.getIdCampEvent() });
    }
}

console.log(paramsList);
console.log(Ext.JSON.encode(paramsList));
if (params.length > 0) {
    //post 
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/CampEvent/UpsertCampEventCabins',
        method: 'POST',
        params: Ext.JSON.encode(paramsList),
        success: function (response, request) {
            var res = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText)
            if (res.success == true) {
                console.log('success');
                thisController.refreshCampEventCabinsForm(form);
            }
            else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Add CampEventCabins Failed', res.message);
            }
        },
        failure: function (response, opts) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', '<p>There was an error trying to save the record:</p><br /><p>The status code was: ' + response.status + '</p><br/><p>The error occurred in the function onMainTabCampEventCabinsFormRender()<p>');
        }


    });
}
```

MVC Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpsertCampEventCabins(IList<ViewModels.CampEventCabin> model)
{
    //a breakpoint here shows that "model" is always null
    return Json(repo.UpsertCampEventCabins(model), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The line "console.log(Ext.JSON.encode(paramsList));" yields this result:

```
[{"idCampEventCabin":0,"Abbreviation":"BH","Accommodations":null,"Capacity":10,"idCabin":2,"Level":"","Name":"Blackhawk","Number":"E2","Type":"Boys","idCampEvent":2},{"idCampEventCabin":0,"Abbreviation":"CH","Accommodations":null,"Capacity":9,"idCabin":3,"Level":"","Name":"Chinook","Number":"D1","Type":"Girls","idCampEvent":2}]
```

One odd thing that I noticed is that when I check the Form Data using Chrome's Developer Tools, there is an extra colon at the end of the JSON string.  Like this:

```
[{"idCampEventCabin":0,"Abbreviation":"BH","Accommodations":null,"Capacity":10,"idCabin":2,"Level":"","Name":"Blackhawk","Number":"E2","Type":"Boys","idCampEvent":2},{"idCampEventCabin":0,"Abbreviation":"CH","Accommodations":null,"Capacity":9,"idCabin":3,"Level":"","Name":"Chinook","Number":"D1","Type":"Girls","idCampEvent":2}]:
```

I want the Controller to accept the JSON data as some Collection of CampEventCabin.  I've tried "List", "IList", "IEnumerable" to no avail.  I've also tried passing the params object without encoding it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be good only. just check with controller flow. As part of ExtJS everything you coded is correct up to my understanding.

have a try over it
 public JsonResult UpsertCampEventCabins(String model)

and then use json parser to manipulate in controller side.

Thanks

Comment: This works.  I added a function "private static T Deserialize<T>(string json)" in order to get the data back into a collection of objects.